# 世界に vs 世界的に, when to use?

Tags: usage

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihGfOC6H4ow
so in this video on Youtube, the title uses "世界に", yet the thumbnail uses 世界的に. What is the difference, why couldn't they simply say "世界に有名Youtuber" (they didn't use a な(!)?). Any explanation would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

First, 世界に有名 is ungrammatical. It should be 世界で有名 as others say.

に as in 世界に注目されている denotes the agent of passive voice, in short, it means （日本のYoutuber）who is stared **by** the world.

Answer (score 1):

世界的に means internationally.
世界に means in the world.

世界的に有名 = famous worldwide/internationally
世界に有名 = famous in the world.

Comment: 世界で有名 is more natural.

Answer (score 0):

世界的に means "world-famous", "international".
世界に means "in the world".

For example:

> それは世界に一つしかない。
>    That is only one in this world.
>   彼は世界的なYoutuberだ。
>   He is famous youtuber in the world. <sup>世界に有名 isn't natural.</sup>